# How to expand aliases in the snakemake shell?

Tags: python, bash, shell, alias, snakemake

Is it possible, to enable bash alias expansion in snakemake?

I'm writing a workflow that is taking a config file for execution parameters.
Let's assume in this config file, the location of a program executable must be defined and will be passed to the shell of a rule.

config.yaml:

```
myProgram: /very/long/path/to/executable/build/myprogram
```

Snakefile:

```py
    rule: runMyProgram
        input: inputfile.txt
        output: outputfile.txt
        shell: "{config[myProgram]} -i {input} -o {output}"
```

But I would  like to also enable the opportunity to directly call the program with the config.yaml:

```
myProgram: myprogram
```

In this case, if the user has set an alias instead of adding *myprogram* to the $PATH, the shell does not recognize the alias and the rule ends with an error. When testing `shopt expand_aliases` within the snakemake shell, I see it is turned off, but adding `shopt -s expand_aliases` to the shell directive of the rule also doesn't do the trick.

I also tried adding the `shopt` command to the `shell.prefix()`, with no success, obviously, as it just adds the prefix to the shell.

While all of us would agree, in this minimal example the user should just put the path to the executable to $PATH, there are circumstances where a user would e.g. use different program versions under different aliases.
Or phrased differently: I would like the program not to crash if a user puts an alias instead of adding it to the $PATH.

Hence I was wondering if there was another possibility to turn on `expand_aliases` globally for Snakemake?

Comment: Does this item from the FAQ help ? If done this way, and the alias is defined in `~/.bashrc`, the shell should find it. https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/project_info/faq.html#i-want-to-configure-the-behavior-of-my-shell-for-all-rules-how-can-that-be-achieved-with-snakemake

Comment: @RobertDavy You mean the `shell.prefix` ? As I wrote, I tried this and it does not work (which is expected, as it only adds the line as prefix in front of every shell command and the alias expansion via `shopt`  doesn't even work manually when added to a specific rule).

Comment: I tried adding the the lines `shell.executable("/bin/bash")` and `shell.prefix("source ~/.bashrc; ")` and found that my usual aliases were respected in subsequent shell calls. I am not clear on what you are trying to do with `shopt`. I am not very familiar with that tool, sorry.